# PHP simple video upload function

Tags: php

I am trying to create a php video upload function, but I can't get it to work.
I get no errors, it just doesn't upload the file. I have checked if it could be the max file size in phpinfo(), but it isn't. The limit is set to 64M.

The paths should be correct, I have triple checked everything. I have even followed the guides, but still nothing.

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['video'])){
    $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
    $type = explode('.', $name);
    $type = end($type); 
    $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
    $random_name = rand();
    $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

    if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'MKV'){
        $message = "Format not supported!!";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$name.'.'.$type); 
        $message = "Successfully uploaded!";
    }
    echo "$message";
}

?>

select video: <br>
    <input type='file' name='video' /><br>
    <input class='btn' type='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the clause containing the `move_uploaded_file()` execute? If so, put in temporary `file_exists()` checks for the source and the target - my guess is you'll find it's a permission issue. The upload works, but you are moving it somewhere the web server does not have permission to write.

Comment: You need to be more careful with your file types - it looks like a PHP file could be uploaded here. Unless you have turned off PHP execution in the `/videos` subfolder, that will permit remote code execution.

Comment: I don't see  how it could be a permission issue. I am running localhost.

I don't care about the security at the moment :D 
Just want to get it to work. 
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should change so you're using `$random_name` in `move_uploaded_file()` even if it's not related to this problem.

Comment: By the way, I would be inclined to move this handling code to the top of the PHP file, and to set message variables for later echoing. It feels a bit strange to render half the form, handle the upload, and then finish rendering.

Comment: :) yea thanks halfer i'll do that. 
Still doesn't work though. 
I have changed the $name back to $random_name. No result

Comment: In what way _exactly_ do you not see it could be a permissions issue? If you can clarify your thinking on that, perhaps we can help further. Also, let us know what the return value is of `move_uploaded_file()` - that will return `false` if there was a problem.

Comment: @MortenPradsgaard Localhost won't protect you from permissions issues.

Comment: I am very new to php :D 
Not sure i can clarify my thoughts any further @halfer

Comment: You said "I don't see how it could be a permission issue. I am running localhost". What did you mean by that? If you think that permission issues do not affect sites running locally, this is not true.

Comment: I'd start by checking permissions on /videos

Comment: How do i check permission issues?

Comment: Did you check the bool return value of the move function already?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Use `$ok = move_uploaded_file( ... )`, using the parameters you have (possibly subject to Chandu's answer).

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in this line,

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$name.'.'.$type);
```

change to

```
$dotpos=strpos($name,'.');
move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.substr($name,0,$dotpos).'.'.$type);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create an `.htaccess` file and define file size configuration there because server will automatically read and enhance size and this is most useful and generic way.

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this configuration resolve the given problem?